# Laravel trigger soft delete on multi level relationships

Tags: laravel, soft-delete

I am trying to delete a parent record which then deletes a multi level relationship.

I have 3 tables: accounts -> services -> service_items

When I delete an account I want the services to be deleted and also all the service_items related to that service.

In my Account model I have the following code

```
public function delete()
{
    $this->services()->delete();
    return parent::delete();
}
```

This is working, when the account is deleted all the related services are deleted, but the service items are not being removed.

I have the following function in my Service model

```
public function delete()
{
    $this->service_items()->delete();
    return parent::delete();
}
```

It seems like this function isn't being triggered when I delete an account. I know I can loop over the services and delete each service_item but I was wondering if there was a way to just trigger the delete function in the Service model?

NOTE: If I directly delete a service the service_items are deleted

Comment: you may want to take  a look this https://github.com/michaeldyrynda/laravel-cascade-soft-deletes

Comment: Use observers to trigger event on basis of CRUD. https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#observers

Answer (score 0):

Alright, so here is the solution.
Instead of deleting each service_item individually, you should use the concept of the hook of the Laravel by declaring the booted method under the model

**Account.php**

```
<?php
class Account extends Model
{
    /**
     * The "booted" method of the model.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected static function booted()
    {
        static::deleted(function($account) {
            $account->services()->delete();
        });
    }

    /**
     * List of services associated with an account.
     */
    public function services()
    {
        // or you may have some other relationship
        return $this->hasMany('App\Service');
    }
}
```

**Service.php**

```
<?php
class Service extends Model
{
    /**
     * The "booted" method of the model.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected static function booted()
    {
        static::deleted(function($service) {
            $service->items()->delete();
        });
    }

    /**
     * List of items associated with an account.
     */
    public function items()
    {
        // or you may have some other relationship
        return $this->hasMany('App\ServiceItem');
    }
}
```

So whenever you delete an account then it will delete all services associated with that account and in turn, it will delete all the service items associated with each service.